# RoR: how make query to return the sum values for each group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum

been teaching myself how to build a simple ruby/rails site. trying now to figure out the caveats for data manipulation. group is working, how do i "sum" all the columns?

index.html.erb

```
<table>

<tr>
<th>Site</th>
<th><7days</th>
<th>>7days</th>
<th>>30days</th>
<th>>90days</th>
<th>>180days</th>
<th>>365days</th>

</tr>
<tr>

<% @gdcomets.each do |dcomet| %>

<td><%= dcomet.site %></td>
<td><%= @sum1 %></td>
<td><%= @sum2 %></td>
<td><%= @sum3 %></td>
<td><%= @sum4 %></td>
<td><%= @sum5 %></td>
<td><%= @sum6 %></td>

</tr>

<% end %>

</table>
```

dcomets_controller

```
class DcometsController < ApplicationController

# GET /dcomets
# GET /dcomets.json
def index

@dcomets = Dcomet.all

@gdcomets = Dcomet.group(:site)

@sum1 = @gdcomets.map(&:ls7day).sum
@sum2 = @gdcomets.map(&:gt7day).sum
@sum3 = @gdcomets.map(&:gt30day).sum
@sum4 = @gdcomets.map(&:gt90day).sum
@sum5 = @gdcomets.map(&:gt180day).sum
@sum6 = @gdcomets.map(&:gt365day).sum


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @gdcomets }
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get better performance letting SQL do the donkey work of summing everything:

```
Dcomet.group(:site).sum(:data)
```

Where :data is the name of column you want to sum. That will return a hash with the keys being the site values, and the values the corresponding sum for that site

Comment: how do i make :data a variable for each of my columns?

Comment: better question, what do i do with this hash to make it into part of the table?

Comment: You can iterate through the hash or sum the values. Up to you. Have a look at the Hash documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html. Also have a play on the command line to see what the output looks like.

Answer (score 1):

```
@sum = @gdcomets.map(&:data).sum
```

:data being the name of the column you want to sum.

Comment: i add that to my index.html or to the controller?

Comment: ive been messing with this a lot this afternoon and something is still not working right. I updated the two files above.

Comment: the output gives the sum of the total columns for each row.